# Syntax error in Fortran OPEN(25,"file.txt",iostat=stat)

Tags: file-io, fortran, syntax-error

Compile time error while executing the following code in Fortran (Code:Blocks IDE).

```
PROGRAM file
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER stat
OPEN(25,"file.dat",iostat=stat)
IF(stat==0) THEN
  print *, "File read complete"
ELSE
   PRINT *, "Err.."
END IF
END PROGRAM file
```

Output:

```
/home/file.f90|7|Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message and more code ([mcve]). Your IDE is irrelevant, tell us your compiler name and version together with the error message. Show us the compiler command you use or the compiler settings in the IDE.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark added the script and its error output.

Comment: The program you've added is different from the initial fragments you had.  Is the line `character ...` not relevant any longer?

Comment: Strange that we do not have a duplicate (at least I haven't found it). I have been bitten by this several times before.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

`OPEN(25,"file.dat",iostat=stat)`
is not correct it should read:
`OPEN(25,FILE="file.dat",iostat=stat)`

From the standard:

```
Syntax of the OPEN statement

R1204 open-stmt is OPEN ( connect-spec-list )

R1205 connect-spec is [ UNIT = ] file-unit-number
  or ACCESS = scalar-default-char-expr
  or ACTION = scalar-default-char-expr
  or ASYNCHRONOUS = scalar-default-char-expr
  or BLANK = scalar-default-char-expr
  or DECIMAL = scalar-default-char-expr
  or DELIM = scalar-default-char-expr
  or ENCODING = scalar-default-char-expr
  or ERR = label
  or FILE = file-name-expr
  or FORM = scalar-default-char-expr
  or IOMSG = iomsg-variable
  or IOSTAT = stat-variable
  or NEWUNIT = scalar-int-variable
  or PAD = scalar-default-char-expr
  or POSITION = scalar-default-char-expr
  or RECL = scalar-int-expr
  or ROUND = scalar-default-char-expr
  or SIGN = scalar-default-char-expr
  or STATUS = scalar-default-char-expr
```

Comment: But the scripts are executing in my server . following are the makefile data

PGM = all

## intel
CMP = ifort
#CMP = ifort -static    #all libraries are linked statically
REAL64 = -real-size 64
BASIC = -save -g -FR  -fpe0  -traceback
SPEED = -O

Comment: looks like i need to install the ifort compiler

Comment: @AKR don't get it. This error can be overcome by setting `FILE="file.dat"`, I assume you already have a Fortran compiler installed, otherwise you couldn't get the error message.

Comment: @AKR, I have just tested your program with ifort (19).  The Intel compiler does accept many non-standard things, but it (in this version) rejects this program with a helpful error message.

Comment: @francescalus , where can I get the ifort compiler, Is it free to download?

Answer (score 0):

In an `open` statement, control is by means of *specifiers*.  In the statement of the question we see an attempt to provide three: the unit to connect to, the filename, and the iostatus.

For all specifiers except for the unit it is necessary to provide them in the form `SPECIFIER=...`.  If the unit is the first in the list, the `unit=` is optional.

So, in this case we must have

```
OPEN(20,file="file.txt",iostat=stat)  ! Optionally, (unit=20, ...)
```

Although the open statement's control list looks like procedure arguments specified by keywords, they are very different things.